# Your connection is not private NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID Nodejs localhost

Tags: node.js, ssl

I'm trying to test ssl on my localhost and getting the error `Your connection is not private` in Chrome. I did change my `/etc/hosts` to add `127.0.0.1 example.com` and going to https://example.com:5001 but still get the error

Here's my code:

```
const https = require('https')
const express = require('express')
const selfsigned = require('selfsigned')

const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('hello'))

const attrs = [{name: 'commonName', value: 'example.com'}]
const pems = selfsigned.generate(attrs, {days: 365})
https.createServer({key: pems.private, cert: pems.cert}, app).listen(5001)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect. You created a self-signed certificate which is of course not trusted by Chrome (where should the trust come from?).  It would be a bad idea if Chrome would trust arbitrary self-signed certificates by default since then an attacker could easily impersonate any server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich so the only way is to get a certificate from approved source like letsencrypt ? What is the use for self signed then?

Comment: It somehow needs to trust the certificate, either by having it issued by a trusted CA or by trusting this certificate explicitly. This means you either need to get a certificate from a trusted CA (like LetsEncrypt) or create an exception for this specific certificate in the browser.

Comment: I think @SteffenUllrich nailed it here. Just to add to the point of about the usage of self-signed certificates, I've seen them being used in closed networks ( maybe LAN network of companies ). These are the cases where you trust that people who are using a website are behind a firewall or a VPN of some sorts and for all the traffic a self-signed cert can be issued.